# Align text to center inside Snackbar (Angular Material)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Hey how can I align text inside SnackBar to be center?

this is my code and it doesn't work:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MaterialService {

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

openSnackBar(message:string){

let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
config.panelClass = 'text-align:center';

  this.snackBar.open(message);
}

}
```

thanks you :)

Comment: `.mat-simple-snackbar {text-align: center;}` works for me

Comment: where did you put this line? @Saka7

Answer (score 6):

Simply add this in your style.css (or any global css, in my case I put it in my app.component.scss)

> **margin:auto;** will center the span tag inside the snackBar
>
> **text-align:center;** will center the text inside the span

```
simple-snack-bar span {
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Settings like this will apply to all your SnackBars.

Answer (score 5):

For angular 7 w/material, I use this in global style.css:

```
.mat-simple-snackbar span {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `panelClass` property of `MatSnackBarConfig` accepts a CSS class which you can define in your main app's `styles.css`:

```ts
openSnackBar(message: string) {
  let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
  config.panelClass = 'center-snackbar';
  this.snackBar.open(message);
}
```

Just make sure you use the `!important` selector as well!

```css
.center-snackbar {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: someone got another answer?

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work :(
The text is inside of a span that's already on the left.

Answer (score 2):

For **on demand** centred text.

SASS:

```
snack-bar-container.text-center {
  span {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Then you add "text-center" to your panelClass

```
let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
config.panelClass = "text-center";
this.snackBar.open(message);
```

That way you can have standard appearance if the Snackbar comes with an action.

Comment: if you already have a generic text-center class, then the redundant text-align is not necessary (sorry no line-breaks available in comments). i.e.:

snack-bar-container.text-center {
  span {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MaterialService {
 horizontalPosition: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'center';
 verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'top';

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

openSnackBar(message:string){

      let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
      config.verticalPosition = this.verticalPosition;
      config.horizontalPosition = this.horizontalPosition;
      this.snackBar.open(message);
}
```

Ref:https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snackbar

Comment: that just moved the snack bar to the top.. I want to center the text inside it

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is quite old, I thought posting my solution might be helpful to someone out there.

After lots of research and some trial and error, the below code is all I needed to get my snackbar working with centered text. (hint: I'm using the most stable Angular version as at today).

```
// extract from my-notification-service.ts file
// Note that I created the above service file, imported "MatSnackBar"
// & "MatSnackBarConfig" from @angular/material/snack-bar, 
// and added a property of type "MatSnackBar" into the constructor. 
// After that, I created the below object and function.
// The function will be called by any submit button in the project.

mySnackBarConfig: MatSnackBarConfig = {
  duration: 3000,
  horizontalPosition: 'center',
  verticalPosition: 'bottom'
}

displayMessage(msg: string) {
  this.mySnackBarConfig['panelClass'] = ['notification','success'];
  this.snackBar.open(msg, '', this.mySnackBarConfig);
}
```

The following code was added to the global styles.css file

```
// extract from styles.css (global)
snack-bar-container.success  {
  background-color: rgb(31, 121, 39);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

snack-bar-container.notification simple-snack-bar  {
  font-size: 18px !important;
}

// this part is all I did to center the text. 
// Take note of the css declaration, not just the style inside.
simple-snack-bar > span {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add center in global css file to work. It worked for me.

```
openSnackBar(message:string){
    
    let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
    config.panelClass = 'center';
    
      this.snackBar.open(message);
    }
```

Add the below code in global css file. It didn't work for me after adding in component.css file

```
 .center {
        text-align: center;
      }
```